# How to correctly answer "apple or orange juice?"?

Tags: questions

How do I answer the question: "apple or orange juice?"?

It's something I've just picked up today.

I've answered with "let's go with apple" and they corrected it "let's go with the apple".

I believe "let's go with apple" is a simple English colloquial speech. "..the apple" sounds more formal.

Am I wrong or right? Are both forms correct?

Comment: Both are understandable, unambiguous and relevant to the question. Why worry about it?

Comment: Who "corrected" you? A native speaker, a collegue, or a teacher?

Comment: A Dutch native. She's a nurse.

Comment: The Dutch native is a little mistaken. The definite article ('the') before 'apple' is correct, but not compulsory in informal speech. Her being a nurse is not relevant.

Comment: "the apple" implies there is specific apple juice, for instance on a menu or in front of you in a store. If it's just a general preference for apple juice, you don't need "the".

Comment: Both forms are correct; using 'the' is less clipped and perhaps less clinical(!) (so I'd choose it in conversation, though I'd rephrase too); neither form warrants correction.